# @RolesAllowed annotation works well with dropwizard resource but not with field level entity filtering

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jax-rs, dropwizard

In my project, I have a need to filter out fields based on roles. Unfortunately it is not working for me.

**Application.Java**

```
environment.jersey().getResourceConfig()
                 .packages("com.test")
                 .register(SecurityEntityFilteringFeature.class).register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class)
                   .register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

**Entity that needs to be filtered**

```
 @RolesAllowed("edit")
    public List<Participant> getParticipants() {
        return participants;
    }
```

**Resource**

```
@Api("test api")
@Path("/api/v1/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Slf4j
@RolesAllowed("participate")
public class TestResource {
@GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve by Id", response = TestResponse.class)
    @UnitOfWork
    public Response getById(@PathParam("id") String testtId) {

        return testService.findById(testId));
    }
}
```

My logged in user is having 2 permissions (edit, participate) and it works well at resource level. But it is not working at entity field level. At field level the logged in role is not considered and it is always filtering that participant field.

Comment: roles allowed only works for resource

Comment: The problem is, that logged in user permissions are overridden by resource method permission. And so the entity is filtered only with "participate" role instead of both user roles. Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem.